# Audio tag alternative for metronome web app

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm new to web development and I've been working on a simple metronome web app. Here it is:

http://anyonecanplayguitar.org/beatkeeper/

JS: http://anyonecanplayguitar.org/beatkeeper/js/simplified.js

I have only limited knowledge regarding including and manipulating audio on a web page, so to create the click I've attached a short audio clip to a timer that fires according to the set beats per minute. In Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, this method works fine. In Safari the audio acts strangely. It fires once loudly, then fires quietly at an inconsistent tempo afterward. Similar behavior is found in IE. I have had no success getting any audio to play on iOS or Android. SO, my question is this: for this application (repeating simple, short clicking sound for use as a steady metronome) how can I ensure smooth audio playback across devices/browsers? Or, perhaps better yet, what are some alternatives to using the audio input tag when desiring to play repeated audio? I'm a newbie, so my knowledge of web audio extends only this far for now. Any guidance (code fixes or alternative methods to experiment with) would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audio tags are pretty inconsistent and can become very tricky if you ever plan on making your app Mobile-friendly.

(Also, testing on Chrome OSX, the beat was not always at the same interval)

I would strongly suggest looking into an existing library (one written recently, since web audio evolves really fast)

A really simple one I know is [Howler](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library)

It defaults to the new Web audio API ([mdn](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/)) and has HTML5 Audio tag fallback. It also features sound sprites, so you can do something like:

```
var sound = new Howl({
  urls: ['sounds.mp3', 'sounds.ogg'],
  sprite: {
    tic: [0, 2000],
    toc: [3000, 700]
  }
});

var currNote = 1;
var currSignature = 4;
var timer = null;
var tempo = 120;

function click(){
    queue(tempo);
    if(currNote ===  currSignature){
        sound.play('toc');
        currNote = 0;
    }
    else{
        sound.play('tic');
    }
    currNote++;
}

function start(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    queue(tempo);
}

function stop(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
}

function queue(tempo){
    timer = setTimeout(click, Math.round(((60/tempo)*1000)*100000) / 100000);
}
```

In this example, I've made a second kind of beat play every 4 clicks (both coming from one single Sound file).

Also : I like to avoid intervals. Not only do I find timeouts more reliable, they also offer more flexible design options.

Comment: Thank you for the info, sir. It'll be a while before I can wrap my head around all of this, but I've got something new to work with!

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer did it for you, do you mind marking it as accepted? If it didn't, how can I make it better ?

Comment: I'm hoping to hear some more suggestions, though I did some playing around with the Web Audio API and came up with this: http://anyonecanplayguitar.org/colorkeyboard/ Now if only all browsers supported it I'd be in business. Thanks again for your help!